Error en la actualización de informe en power BI web
Tengo un archivo pbix en power BI web, el cual tiene una actualización programada. Después de revisar si actualizó; observo que muestra un signo que indica que hubo un error en la actualización el cual contiene el siguiente texto:
"Error del origen de datosExpression.Error: The key didn't match any rows in the table.. Key"
He investigado en algunas páginas y solo hay solución para aquellos tableros que consumen de un Excel, sin embargo, el mío consume directamente de una base de datos.
He intentado actualizar el informe desde power bi desktop, meter las credenciales y no he tenido éxito.

No has tenido éxito al introducir las claves o al intentar actualizar el informe desde Power Bi Desktop?
Ese mensaje es debido a que en algún paso a la hora de combinar alguna consulta no está encontrando la clave que une ambas tablas. Revisa que las claves de ambas tablas sean del mismo tipo de dato.

He podido actualizarlos desde desktop, sin embargo al subirlo a power bi web marca error al actualizarse el informe.

Hice la prueba al subirlo a otro espacio de trabajo en web y actualiza bien, no se si tiene que ver algo eso.

Puede ser que tu modelo, en el primer espacio de trabajo tenga algún problema. Borra el modelo y el informe en ese espacio y vuelva a intentar cargarlo desde Desktop.

soluciones reapuntando el tablero y metiendo las credenciales, hasta el momento no ha marcado error en las siguientes actualizaciones. Gracias por el apoyo
